How to anchor french cleats on a wall that is longer than the individual cleats
I want to hang french cleats for the entire span of a garage wall (25'). My question is where do you plan to anchor the end to end joint of one cleat to the next?
Do you have them end 8 inches between studs? Or do you have them end and start on the center of the stud and screw two screws into the single stud (one for the end of a cleat and another for the start of a cleat).
I think I saw a video that said 4" (height) cleats would have zero waste on a sheet so I will probably cut them that size. That would let me offset the screws 1 or 2 inches. No plans on using a backer board.
Thanks

Hi, welcome to Woodworking! OK frst off, for a multitude of reasons (incl. expected load, the spread of the load) the cleats that attach to the wall don't need to hit studs for them to be strong enough to work, assuming decent drywall anchors are used. So missing a cleat here or there, while mostly fastening into studs across the span is going to be fine. Does that put your mind at rest about where the joins may fall?

Agree that the end of the cleat is fairly unimportant with long cleats (I’d butt them on a stud, personally), but would encourage you to hit studs every time possible.
Drywall anchors will work up to a certain load, and that’s usually pretty substantial, especially when spread out over a large span, but there’s a point where they do get overloaded. Plus, a drywall anchor is a two step install, where a screw into a stud is just one step.
Edit to add a couple of links to show that sometimes drywall anchors are not sufficient.
floating vanity fail
cabinet down!

Drywall anchors will work up to a certain load True. But the problem in a situation like this is that the use of the cleat may vary over time. If every segment of cleat is in at least two studs then you're in good shape, which (based on 16" spacing) should be fine as long as each segment is at least a couple feet long.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, with decent anchors the idea that we must hit studs as much as possible is largely baseless, as test after test confirms. Can you envisage a reasonable use of a French cleat system where a single cleat is overloaded? I can't. Nobody is hanging an engine block from a single cleat (although they could!). Based on weak anchors nobody would voluntarily pick, and a bare minimum per individual cleat, 2 each end and 2 in the centre that one cleat could hold 240lb. Add only 2 more in the middle and you add 80 in this thought experiment, while in reality it's much more.

I appreciate the responses. If the cleat is 4 inches and I butt them on the stud is it too hard / damaging on the stud to put screws in 2 inches apart? A screw an inch from the top on the left cleat and a screw an inch up from the bottom on the right cleat.

Not damaging at all. If you were being really fancy, you could put 45° cuts on the butting ends and get the screw right in the middle of the stud.

If in doubt, drill pilot holes (even if the screw container claims they're not necessary). You can give yourself further peach of mind by driving in every screw that goes into a stud at an angle – never upwards, but downwards (head above point) and/or leaning left or right. This maximises potential hold for single screws.
